# Javascript, Compose Key and Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, keyevent

The intended application is a simple typing practice program, for reference.
At present, things work fine in Windows, I've not tried on macos,
but under Linux I can't handle source texts with accents.

Under Windows, with WinCompose, if I use a compose-key sequence, e.g. Compose-'-e
then the browser receives a single keypress event with key=é.

I'd like to get the same under Linux.
That is, to get the result of a compose key sequence (in this case é) and ignore
keypresses in that sequence (i.e. not receive Compose, ' and e).

Is there a 'right' way to do this?